# How to map a kebind to a operator?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, vscode, plugin-nerdcommenter

I am using nerd-commenter which uses the operator series `gcc` to toggle comment.

I would like to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to `gcc` because I prefer the VsCode mapping.

So is there any way to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to `gcc`?

Comment: does `nmap <silent> <c-_> gcc`
and `xmap <silent> <c-_> gc_`  work?

Comment: This works thank you!